# Can LUKS be used in a similar way as veracrypt?

Tags: encryption, luks, veracrypt

I am in the process of eliminating non-free code from my machines.

I currently am using Veracrypt to lock some files behind encryption, and quite like that I have a .vc file I can easily backup and move.

I want to reproduce this with LUKS, however, all documentation I find make it look like it is aimed to encrypt devices, like USB keys, disks, partitions... Which is really useful, but does not lend itself to have a multitude of encrypted files, or easily making backup of thoses.

Can LUKS be used to have the filesystem in a encrypted file instead of a device ?

Comment: Uhm, your ambition is awesome, but what is it that you consider non-free about VeraCrypt? Because your question certainly suggests it is ... btw, if I were you I'd check out zuluCrypt and zuluMount which has support for a variety of containers, including VeraCrypt ones. I for one still prefer VeraCrypt as it would allow me to do it on multiple systems whereas LUKS once again would limit my choices. But YMMV, so just _commenting_ here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can. You can encrypt a file (but you need to have it already created), treating it like a regular block device. Here is a test I did with a zeroed out file that I created with dd.

```
  # dd if=/dev/zero of=./test.dd bs=1024 count=10000
  10000+0 records in
  10000+0 records out
  10240000 bytes (10 MB, 9.8 MiB) copied, 0.020574 s, 498 MB/s
  # cryptsetup luksFormat ./test.dd
  
  WARNING!
  ========
  This will overwrite data on ./test.dd irrevocably.
  
  Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
  Enter passphrase for ./test.dd:
  <...>
  <...>
```